# disable submit while correct forms not filled js

Tags: javascript

i have issue with disable submit  while corrects forms not filled. My code working, but need do some changes and idk how to solve it.
My js

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    validate();
    $('#InputEventDate, #InputEventText').change(validate);
});

function validate(){
    if ($('#InputEventDate').val().length   >   0   &&
        $('#InputEventText').val().length    >   0) {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

So i have form, in what form event time input and event text are necessary. So i disabled button and checking with what js length. Problem is they not check real time, need click something then my button becomes not disabled.
I try change js like this.

```
$('#InputEventText').val($(this).val().length)   >   0
```

But then i chose data, write idk why 10 in my event form and do nothing, submit not change to not disabled. Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Can you provide minimal example inside SO Snippet?

Comment: You need to remove disabled attribute, and that will again be available to click

Comment: I need available to click  while user write text.

Comment: Is your `change` event fired? Put a breakpoint or print in it

Comment: Also, we need to see your HTML

Comment: it will be very big html code, who are basic form html with inlut who have id. and submit button who must be available  to click when selected

Comment: [maybe useful](https://testbed.nicon.nl/showFiddle/k8nLrsve)

Answer (score 0):

when your validation process done you can send data using javascript

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    // response -> this.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "URL", true);
xhttp.send(Data);
```

OR

use onsubmit event in your form tag. do validation in that event.

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
```

Comment: Don't mix HTML and JS

Comment: I know it's not good practice. thank you @ChayimFriedman. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vanilla javascript, you'll need to do a few things.

1. Set state for each input. It depends on how many inputs you have. For example, `isNameValid = false`;
2. Create an on change event listener and attach it to all inputs you want to track. Inside the event listener you need to validate the input, mark the input as valid and run a function that checks whether all input states are true. If all states are true, enable the button, otherwise disable it.